# drag/drop a *part* of a row?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement a UI feature.
I'm working on a scheduling app for a small music competition in my town.
There are time slots, and students performing. We assign a kid a time, but something *always* comes up and kids have to be rearranged. So let's say the schedule is set up as a table something along the lines of
11:00 joe smith
11:20 sally jones
11:40 john doe
All good until joe smith learns he has a soccer practice and can't make it at 11:00. I'd love to be able to drag joe's name into a different position **without** moving the time itself ("joe smith" moves, 11:00 does **not** move).
Does that make sense? Has anyone faced this issue before? I will need to write the updated data (including the time) back to a database, so the time somehow has to be bound to the student, not just some visual thing. I'm more comfortable with jQuery than some of the other javascript/ajax frameworks, so that's the environment I hope to work in.
Thanks for any pointers.
Steve

Comment: People will be more likely to help if you accept some answers on your questions.

Comment: check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable. looks like it may be what you're looking for

Comment: @heymrcarter - I've looked at that, but was under the impression one could only drag an entire table row. Not true? I could make td elements within a tr draggable? Hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I would make a grid using tables. Table cells represent times, DIVs placed in the cells represent students. When dragging you read the parent element's time, drag the student, read the drop parent's time and update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion - so potentially I would make the table 2 cells wide - the first td containing the time, the second td containing a draggable div? And I could get those divs to swap places with one another within their td elements? Hmmm!Thanks!

Comment: No, each TD contains one DIV. You can put the time in the TD and give the DIV some margin-top so it doesn't cover up the time. You insert the DIV into the target table cell after dropping.

Comment: Also, you can stash hidden data in elements using jQuery. Very handy.: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Thanks Diodeus. My head won't get around this tonight. I'll try again tomorrow.  :-)  Steve